# Flutter hot restart not saving files in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When I do hot restart in vscode for flutter code, it is not saving files but is completing hot restart process hence making no changes. I have to manually save the files. This problem is faced recently. Vscode would automatically save the files when performing hot restart before but  now it is not saving files. I have to manually save this files. Please help if there is any solution for saving files automatically during hot restart in vscode.

(What I've tried, uninstalling and reinstalling of vscode, searcing around the settings but found none relevent settings).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the auto save option is checked under files -> Auto Save if its unchecked click it and try again. see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: This is a different feature that can be annoying in case the user doesn't want to save / hot reload that often. What OP means is that when user decides to hot reload the files that have changes should save automatically instead of manually.